# ZODB / ZEO . Connecting to server from client

Tags: python, database, zodb

Basically I can use ZODB fine. However the ZEO tutorials are all very confusing.

From my understanding you start a server by going into my directory and punchign into the command prompt

python runzeo.py -C zeo.config

Where my zeo.config file is as follows

```
<zeo>
  address localhost:8090
</zeo>

<filestorage>
  path C:\\Anaconda\\Lib\\site-packages\\ZEO\\var\\tmp\\Data.fs
</filestorage>

<eventlog>
  <logfile>
    path C:\\Anaconda\\Lib\\site-packages\\ZEO\\var\\tmp\\zeo.log
    format %(asctime)s %(message)s
  </logfile>
</eventlog>
```

When I run it the log file is filled with

```
2014-07-02T14:49:15 (1948) opening storage '1' using FileStorage
2014-07-02T14:49:15 StorageServer created RW with storages:     1:RW:C:\\Anaconda\\Lib\\site-packages\\ZEO\\var\\tmp\\Data.fs
2014-07-02T14:49:15 (1948) listening on ('localhost', 8090)
```

Now when I try to get a client to add some random stuff to the database with prints after every line to see how its going:

```
from ZEO.ClientStorage import ClientStorage
from ZODB import DB
import transaction


print "starting"
storage=ClientStorage(('localhost',8090))
print "storage opened"
db=DB(storage)
conn=db.open()
print "connection opened" 
root=conn.root()
print "established connection"
root['letters']=['a','b','c']
print "added values"
transaction.commit()
print "transaction done"
root.close()
print "closed"
```

My code only prints "starting", no error messages are thrown, so Im assuming that its getting stuck on the storage = ClientStorange(('localhost',8090)) line, my Data.fs file remains unchanged. I have no idea what is wrong and I have consulted all the tutorials.

I'm on Windows using Python 2.7 and installed ZEO / ZODB from pip so I assume they are all up to date versions is that helps.

Any help or pointers to different object orientated databases (with multiple proccess access) would be appreciated.

Thanks everyone

Comment: Just to rule something out, you might want to verify that 'localhost' is what you think it is when resolving (e.g. ipv4, not ipv6, etc)...  Does substituting 127.0.0.1 for localhost in ClientStorage construction make any difference?

Comment: Worked it out but cheers for giving it a shot anyway mate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer to my own question. Seems there is a bug with the implementation of using the localhost in windows. (Running server and client on same machine)

The source code needs an edit:

> I have the same problem (can't connect to ZEO Server) using ZODB/ZEO 4.0 with Python 2.7.6 on Windows.
>
> The proposed solution (changing line 446 of ZEO/zrpc/client.py) works for me, so why not incorporate the patch into the 4.0 release too?
>
> ```
> - socket.getaddrinfo(host or 'localhost', port)
> + socket.getaddrinfo(host or 'localhost', port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM)"
> ```

From https://bugs.launchpad.net/zodb/+bug/1004513